# How to add references to another field besides ID on Rails model generation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a simple app using the [SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/documentation#intro) and I'm struggling with the model creation.

Let's take the People resources from the API (without Films), for example:

Attributes:

```
name string -- The name of this person.
birth_year string -- The birth year of the person, using the in-universe standard of BBY or ABY - Before the Battle of Yavin or After the Battle of Yavin. The Battle of Yavin is a battle that occurs at the end of Star Wars episode IV: A New Hope.
eye_color string -- The eye color of this person. Will be "unknown" if not known or "n/a" if the person does not have an eye.
gender string -- The gender of this person. Either "Male", "Female" or "unknown", "n/a" if the person does not have a gender.
hair_color string -- The hair color of this person. Will be "unknown" if not known or "n/a" if the person does not have hair.
height string -- The height of the person in centimeters.
mass string -- The mass of the person in kilograms.
skin_color string -- The skin color of this person.
homeworld string -- The URL of a planet resource, a planet that this person was born on or inhabits.
species array -- An array of species resource URLs that this person belongs to.
starships array -- An array of starship resource URLs that this person has piloted.
vehicles array -- An array of vehicle resource URLs that this person has piloted.
url string -- the hypermedia URL of this resource.
created string -- the ISO 8601 date format of the time that this resource was created.
edited string -- the ISO 8601 date format of the time that this resource was edited.
```

So I was thinking about the following model for Rails:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :birth_year
      t.string :eye_color
      t.string :gender
      t.string :hair_color
      t.string :height
      t.string :mass
      t.string :skin_color
      t.references :homeworld, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :planets }
      t.references :species, null: false, foreign_key: true, array: true, default: []
      t.text :starships, array: true, default: []

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Since what I need is actually an array with the URLs of homeworld, species and starships, I'm not sure if I adding the id from each (from t.references) is the proper way to add each field.

- Can I get only the URL from each, even though I don't have a id referencing it?
- Does the "`array: true, default: []`" syntax work properly for what I need, as an array?

Answer (score 0):

*starships*, *species* and *vehicles* are many to many relations.

You can solve this by an array column and some custom logic or via a "join table". The latter is, IMHO, preferred and what DBs are good at.

The associations can be stup approx. like this:

```rb
class Starship < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :starship_possessions
  has_many :people, through: :starship_possessions
  ...
end

class StarshipPossession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :starship
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :starship_possessions
  has_many :starships, through: :starship_possessions
  ...
end
```

and the `StarshipPossession` table at least has `id`, 'starship_id' (FK) and `person_id` (FK) but could, depending business requirements and data also contain information about start/enbd date of ownership and so on.

When importing a Person into your DB then you can do following steps for each starship URL

Check if the starship exists or if not, create it

```rb
def find_starship(starship_url)
  starship = Starship.find_or_initialize_by(url: starship_url)
  return starship if starship.persisted?
  # it's a new starship, fetch data and update
  starship_data = fetch_starship_data_via_api(starship_url)
  starship.some_property = starship_data.some_property # depending on the data structure returned you could just use 'update'
  starship.save!
  starship
end
```

Associate it to the person (perhaps first check if it is not associated yet)

```rb
StarshipPossession.create!(starship: starship, person: person)
# or
person.starships.create!(starship: starship)
# or 
starship.people.create!(person: person)
```

Obviously this is written without having a running example of the code, so there might be some problems (e.g. in my use of people vs person).

There are some things to note:

- I assume that a Person can own a starship only once. So you should probably add a unique key to the starship_possessions table for `[person_id,starship_id]`
- I used  the bang (`!`) versions for `save!` and `create!` to raise an exception when something goes wrong, so I notice immediately when there is an error

Comment: I see! I got it as well. But in the case of Person, it belongs_to a Planet, so it would be a 1:N relationship, without the need of a join table, right? In fact, if I only needed the ID from the planet I can see how it would be enough.
But from what I can tell, I need a join table to get the planet's URL for example, isn't it?

Comment: yes, person:homeworld is a 1:N.

You can use the same logic. Lookup the homeworld by URL. If it does not exist create it. Then assign to the person.